# How to plot the empirical distribution function in oxyplot?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, oxyplot

I have data that are points of the empirical distribution function

```
ICollection<DataModelXY> data {get; set;}

class DataModelXY
{
  public double X {get; set;}
  public double Y {get; set;}
}
```

I need do draw function like that
[image: First example]

or that
[image: Second example]

Alas, in the oxyplot there is only StairStepSeries which builds the wrong thing
[image: Example in oxyplot]

Need that without lines under red cross:
[image: Need that without lines under red cross]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two properties on `StairStepSeries`, `VerticalLineStyle` and `VerticalStrokeThickness`.

Try to set `VerticalLineStyle="None"` (for some reason `None` doesn't work for me) and if it won't work you can set `VerticalStrokeThickness="0"`.

```
<oxy:Plot>
    <oxy:Plot.Series>
        <oxy:StairStepSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Points}" 
             VerticalLineStyle="None" VerticalStrokeThickness="0">
        </oxy:StairStepSeries>
    </oxy:Plot.Series>
</oxy:Plot>
```